# Ubuntu dnu restore scripts

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, dnu

I've got a problem with 'dnu restore' command in Ubuntu 15 trying to build an ASP.NET 5 application. If I add SignalR to dependencies in project.json, no JS scripts are added to my project directory. Visual Studio Code continues asking me to restore packages. The same situation with jQuery (yes, I know it's better to use Bower for it's installation). I've tried running command with '--no-cache' parameter and adding SignalR-Client dependency, but scripts are still not added. It seems like Server-side libs are installed successfully (project builds and runs when I inherit from SignalR Hub class, the only problem VS Code does not recognize installed namespaces and classes). Is it possible to fix it or should I manually download JS files?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason. ASP.NET 5 packaging system is new for me so I didn't know how to use it properly. DNX doesn't know how to install client libraries at all. It places all the installed packages into a special directory shared by all projects. In order to install client packages Bower should be used (it is easy to add - just add a dependency in project.json and create a configuration file). By the way SignalR has it's own Bower package as well as jQuery (but this is obvious).